# set component page parameter dynamically

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

Im setting a component in a custom page template like the following. This means that the nodeRef parameter will be set by url. Is it possible to set the nodeRef parameter by code dynamically?

thank you!

```
<sub-components>
    <sub-component id="default">
       <evaluations>
          <evaluation>
             <evaluators>
                <evaluator type="config.component.evaluator">
                   <params>
                      <element>DocumentDetails/document-details/display-web-preview</element>
                   </params>
                </evaluator>
             </evaluators>
             <url>/components/preview/web-preview</url>
             <properties>
                <nodeRef>{nodeRef}</nodeRef>
                <api>api</api>
                <proxy>alfresco</proxy>
                <dependencyGroup>document-details</dependencyGroup>
             </properties>
          </evaluation>
       </evaluations>
    </sub-component>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. In your example the /components/preview/web-preview is pointing to a web script. The web script has a controller (web-preview.get.js) and in that controller it grabs the nodeRef param and does something with it.

If you want to use a different nodeRef, you can extend that web script and enhance the logic accordingly.

For example, I recently needed to change the nodeRef that the previewer displays. Instead of showing the current node's content I wanted to show a related node's content. So I extended web-preview.get.js and changed the Alfresco.WebPreview widget instantiation to use the nodeRef that I fetched from an association instead of the nodeRef that was passed in.

Comment: Jeff, how to get a nodeRef in server side javascript in the share tier? I believe I will need to develop a server side webscript that will return the nodeRef right? Because in server side javascript at the share tier I dont think I can get a workflow or task object in order to get the documents related with the workflow/task.

Comment: Another approach would be to get the nodeRef usign client-side javascript, searching for the nodeRef in the resulting task html. The problem here is that I dont know where to put my client side javascript... maybe in the freemarket ftl template? And if yes, then how using javscript I may set the pdf viewer with the nodeRef? Can I use javscript to get the pdf object and then set the properties? thank you!

Comment: You should spend some time dissecting the existing source code. It holds many of the answers you are looking for.